# pandas return dataframe rows that are not numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have a dataframe:

```
  Region     Value       ID
    Asia       N/A    XYAZZ
    Asia       '0'    ZSJDS
    EMEA       '2'    KKKKK
    USME    '0.50'    KLJSA
    APAC    NODATA    JKUUS
    APAC    '1.00'    JKUUC
```

In 'Value' column I have strings that may contain a number as string, N/A or any other string.
I need a code that will return me any values that are NOT in this range: 0 < x <= 1, like this:

```
  Region     Value       ID
    Asia       N/A    XYAZZ
    Asia       '0'    ZSJDS
    EMEA       '2'    KKKKK
    APAC    NODATA    JKUUS
```

I tried something like this

```
  data_types_dict = {'Value': float}
  df = df.astype(data_types_dict, errors='ignore')
  df = df[(df['Value'] <= 0) | (df['Value'] > 1)]
```

but it works only when there are only numbers and string-numbers, it fails when converting NODATA to float.
I thought that I could first filter out all rows with strings that are non convertible to float, then perform the above operation, then concat it, like this:

```
df1 = df1['Value'].StringsNonFloat
df2 = df[(df['Value'] <= 0) | (df['Value'] > 1)]
final_df = concat([df1, df2])
```

but is this pythonic? is there such a function?

**Edit for Wilian**

thats my data before and after:

```
print(' - - - BEFORE - - - :')
print(df['Value'].head(27).to_dict())
df = df[~(df['Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull() & df['Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').between(0, 1, inclusive='right'))]
print(' - - - AFTER - - - :')
print(df['Value'].head(27).to_dict())
```

Output:

```
 - - - BEFORE - - - :
{24: '-1', 67: 'NODATA', 114: '1.1', 148: '-1', 164: '0', 326: '1.1', 370: '0.012', 682: '0.012', 861: '0', 900: '', 1120: '0.012', 1226: '0.12775331008000002', 1329: '0.028300000000000002', 1512: '0.012', 1540: '0.012', 1783: '0.012', 1788: 'N/A', 1900: '0.012', 1927: '0.048', 2127: '0.012', 2137: '0.012', 2236: '0.012', 2265: '0.012', 2515: '0.012', 2713: '0.012', 2807: '1.0', 2843: '1.0'}
 - - - AFTER- - - :
{24: '-1', 67: 'NODATA', 114: '1.1', 148: '-1', 326: '1.1', 900: '', 1788: 'N/A'}
```

line 164 and 861 are missing.
At the same time '' from line 900 or N/A from 1788 are catched, the problem is clearly with 0.

In Excel, 164 is '0 , and 861 is just 0, but the point is that I can't trust that data and there might more more sources in the future so it must all happen here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for something like this:

```
df = df[(df["Value"].astype(float) > 1) | (df["Value"].astype(float) <= 0)]
```

So taking the data frame where the value as type float is greater than one or less than/equal to 0.

This is very similar to your code but using .astype(float) instead.

**Edit** (following comments)

I would do the following:

Start by converting value to float if possible

```
df["Value"] = [float(value) if value.isdigit() else value for value in df["Value"]]
```

Then subset by only those that are float:

```
df = df[df["Value"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,float))]
```

Then subset again by those that are in the desired range:

```
df = df[(df["Value"] > 1) | (df["Value"] <= 0)]
```

Comment: I am using .astype() above as a dictionary, but even if I change it the way you propose, is still fails on 'NODATA' records:  
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NODATA'

Comment: Do you need to differentiate between NODATA and N/A for subsequent analysis or are you able to convert all to NaN?

Comment: I need to differentiate because I am going to return all those that are not in the range as breaks and report to the analyst

Comment: Okay I have made an edit.

Comment: Unfortunately still not correct, It catches only 0s :/

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[~(df['Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull() & df['Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').
    between(0, 1, inclusive='right'))]

print(df)
```

output:

```
  Region   Value     ID
0   Asia     NaN  XYAZZ
1   Asia       0  ZSJDS
2   EMEA       2  KKKKK
4   APAC  NODATA  JKUUS
```

Comment: Almost, in my data it doesn't return the 0s, only indexes 0,2,4 from your output, what might be the reason?
If I change to between(0.0001, 1) it works. It just treats 0 as inclusive despite parameter set to 'right'

Comment: run your code with "print(df.to_dict())" (right after creating the df variable) and paste here the output.

Comment: I included everything in the Edit